# php Blocking flooding request by session or IP

Tags: php, session, request, ip, flooding

I want to block flooding requests by session or IP.

This is my requirement. **If any user send 1000 requests within 1 hour**, I want to **block** that request. I don't know it's done by session or IP. Please help me to do this. Please provide script if you have. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be a combination of both of them.
use session because he might change the IP.
use IP because he might block session cookies.